# Python iteration: sorting through a .txt file extract wanted data

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have a sample inputfile.txt:

```
chr1    34870071    34899867    pi-Fam168b.1    -
chr11   98724946    98764609    pi-Wipf2.1  +
chr11   105898192   105920636   pi-Dcaf7.1  +
chr11   120486441   120495268   pi-Mafg.1   -
chr12   3891106 3914443 pi-Dnmt3a.1 +
chr12   82815946    82882157    pi-Map3k9.1 -
chr13   23855536    23856215    pi-Hist1h1a.1   +
chr13   55206682    55236190    pi-Zfp346.1 +
chr1    95700553    95718679    pi-Ing5.1   +
chr13   55313417    55419685    pi-Nsd1.1   +
chr14   27852218    27920472    pi-Il17rd.1 +
chr14   65430438    65568699    pi-Hmbox1.1 -
chr1    120524521   120581739   pi-Tfcp2l1.1    +
chr15   81633147    81657289    pi-Tef.1    +
chr15   89331804    89390691    pi-Shank3.1 +
chr15   103021983   103070259   pi-Cbx5.1   -
chr16   16896549    16927451    pi-Ppm1f.1  +
chr16   17233679    17263523    pi-Hic2.1   +
chr16   17452059    17486929    pi-Crkl.1   +
chr16   24393531    24992661    pi-Lpp.1    +
chr16   43964878    43979143    pi-Zdhhc23.1    -
chr17   25098236    25152532    pi-Cramp1l.1    -
chr17   27993451    28036985    pi-Uhrf1bp1.1   +
chr17   83973363    84031786    pi-Kcng3.1  -
chr1    133904194   133928161   pi-Elk4.1   +
chr18   60844148    60908308    pi-Ndst1.1  -
chr19   10057193    10059582    pi-Fth1.1   +
chr19   44637337    44650762    pi-Hif1an.1 +
chr1    135027714   135036359   pi-Ppp1r15b.1   +
chr2    28677821    28695861    pi-Gtf3c4.1 -
chr1    136651241   136852527   pi-Ppp1r12b.1   -
chr2    154262219   154365092   pi-Cbfa2t2.1    +
chr2    156022393   156135687   pi-Phf20.1  +
chr3    51028854    51055547    pi-Ccrn4l.1 +
chr3    94985683    95021902    pi-Gabpb2.1 -
chr1    158488203   158579750   pi-Abl2.1   +
chr4    45411294    45421633    pi-Mcart1.1 -
chr4    56879897    56960355    pi-D730040F13Rik.1  -
chr4    59818521    59917612    pi-Snx30.1  +
chr4    107847846   107890527   pi-Zyg11a.1 -
chr4    107900359   107973695   pi-Zyg11b.1 -
chr4    132195002   132280676   pi-Eya3.1   +
chr4    134968222   134989706   pi-Rcan3.1  -
chr4    136025678   136110697   pi-Luzp1.1  +
chr1    162933052   162964958   pi-Zbtb37.1 -
chr5    38591490    38611628    pi-Zbtb49.1 -
chr5    67783388    67819359    pi-Bend4.1  -
chr5    114387108   114443767   pi-Ssh1.1   -
chr5    115592990   115608225   pi-Mlec.1   -
chr5    143628624   143656891   pi-Fbxl18.1 -
chr1    172123561   172145541   pi-Uhmk1.1  -
chr6    83312367    83391602    pi-Tet3.1   -
chr6    85419571    85434653    pi-Fbxo41.1 -
chr6    116288039   116359551   pi-March08.1    +
chr6    120786229   120842859   pi-Bcl2l13.1    +
chr7    71031236    71083761    pi-Klf13.1  -
chr7    107068766   107128968   pi-Rnf169.1 -
chr7    139903770   140044311   pi-Fam53b.1 -
chr8    72285224    72298794    pi-Zfp866.1 -
chr8    106872110   106919708   pi-Cmtm4.1  -
chr8    112250549   112261649   pi-Atxn1l.1 -
chr10   41901651    41911816    pi-Foxo3.1  -
chr8    119682164   119739895   pi-Gan.1    +
chr8    125406988   125566154   pi-Ankrd11.1    -
chr9    27148219    27165314    pi-Igsf9b.1 +
chr9    44100521    44113717    pi-Hinfp.1  -
chr9    61761092    61762348    pi-Rplp1.1  -
chr9    106590412   106691503   pi-Rad54l2.1    -
chr9    114416339   114473487   pi-Trim71.1 -
chr9    119311403   119351032   pi-Acvr2b.1 +
chr9    119354082   119373348   pi-Exog.1   +
chr10   82822985    82831579    pi-D10Wsu102e.1 +
chr10   126415753   126437016   pi-Ctdsp2.1 +
chr1    90159688    90174093    pi-Hjurp.1  -
chr11   60591039    60597792    pi-Smcr8.1  +
chr11   69209318    69210176    pi-Lsmd1.1  +
chr11   75345218    75391069    pi-Slc43a2.1    +
chr11   79474214    79511524    pi-Rab11fip4.1  +
chr11   95818479    95868022    pi-Igf2bp1.1    -
chr11   97223641    97259855    pi-Socs7.1  +
chr11   97524530    97546757    pi-Mllt6.1  +
chr1    120355721   120355843   1-qE2.3-2.1 -
chr2    120518324   120540873   2-qE5-4.1   +
chr7    82913927    82926993    7-qD2-40.1  -
```

Column1=chromosome_number

Column2=start

Column3=end

Column4=gene_name

Column5=Orientation (either + or -)

1.) I need to extract lines that have the **same chromosome number** (column1), **their start sites have a difference of 200 Maximum (so 200 or less)** (column2) that are in **opposite** orientation (one is plus/minus).

This is what I have so far and not sure where my mistake is:

```
import csv
import itertools as it
f=open('inputfile.txt', 'r')

def getrecords(f):
    for line in open(f):
        yield line.strip().split()
key=lambda x: x[0]
for i, rec in it.groupby(sorted(getrecords('inputfile.txt'), key=key), key=key):
    for c0, c1 in it.combinations(rec, 2):
        if (c0[4]!= c1[4] and (abs(int(c0[1])-int(c1[1]))) < 200):
            print ("%s\t%s\t%s" % (c0[0], c0[1], c0[3]))
            print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (c1[0], c1[1], c1[3]))
```

*Please note: this code runs, but does not give out any output, when I am certain there should be something*
I am expecting there to be around 15 unique sequence lines. 
Expected output:

```
ChrX   start_number1            gene_name1
ChrX   start_number1+/-200      gene_name2
ChrY   start_number2            gene_name3
ChrY   start_number2+/-200      gene_name4
```

Then I'd sort through these lines to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: I get output when I run your code.

Comment: @jfsturtz Sorry for the confusion, I had         if (c0[4]!= c1[4] and (abs(int(c0[1])-int(c1[1]))) > 200): WIth the '>' sign that looks for the difference between two start sites being 200 or greater. I changed it to 200 or less through '<' and I get no output

Comment: This might be a dumb observation, but ... **are** there any records in your file with the same chromosome number and start site within 200 of one another?  I can't find any.  It looks to me like you wrote your code properly, but what you're looking for just isn't there.  If you change 200 to 200000, you get output (and even then, not very much).

Answer (score 1):

There are no values in your example that meet your specified criteria, so I added a single line to your `inputfile.txt`:

```
chr1    34870091    34899887    pi-Fam168b.1 +
```

I copied the first line of your `inputfile.txt` and added `20` to the integers in the second and third columns.

To begin, you don't need to import `csv`, you won't use it.  You should import [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), I'll explain below.

```
from itertools import groupby,product
from operator import itemgetter
```

This block is just parsing your `inputfile.txt` into a usable data structure (list of dictionaries) where each record in the file will be a `dictionary` element in the `sites` list.

```
with open('/home/kevin/inputfile.txt', 'rb') as f: # should use with open()
    sites = []  #list to hold each record as a dictionary
    for row in f:
        row = tuple(row.strip().split())
        d = {'chr': row[0], 'start': row[1], 'stop':row[2], 'gene_name':row[3], 'strand':row[4]}
        sites.append(d)
```

I chose to first, sort by *strand* using `itemgetter`,  Now, when you `groupby` strand we can separate the dictionaries into list of all the `plus` strands and a list of all the `minus` strands:

```
plus = []
minus = []

for elmt,grp in groupby(sites, itemgetter('strand')): # sites is our sorted list of dicts
    for item in grp:
        if elmt == '+':
            plus.append(item)
        else:
            minus.append(item)
```

Now you can iterate through `plus` and `minus` using `product`, which acts like a nested for loop and compare `start` positions:

```
for p,m in product(plus,minus):
    if p['chr'] == m['chr'] and abs(int(p['start']) - int(m['start'])) < 200:
            print ("%s\t%s\t%s") % (p['chr'], p['start'], p['gene_name'])
            print ("%s\t%s\t%s") % (m['chr'], m['start'], m['gene_name'])
```

This returned:

```
chr1    34870091    pi-Fam168b.1 #remember I artificially added this one
chr1    34870071    pi-Fam168b.1
```

As a reference, this type of task may be more elegantly achieved in the python library [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).  [Bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (C++ i think) is specifically designed to work with `.bed` files, which is the format you're working with.  HTH!

Comment: thank you so much! i came to the same conclusion. This answers my question in just a detailed manner. Thank you again!